# How to remove header line store in SQL Server?

Tags: apache-nifi

i have try to move data into sql server with following processor flow.

```
1.GetFile
2.SplitText
3.ExtractText
4.ReplaceText
5.putSQL
```

i can able to move all data into SQL Server but it store header information also into server.

How to avoid header information stored in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SplitText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitText/index.html) has a property called **Header Line Count** which defaults to `0`. Change this value to `1` or however many header lines are present in your incoming data.

If the header is not contained to a specific line, you can also use regular expressions in `ExtractText` or `ReplaceText` to excise it.